# Sqlite import from file with custom delimiter?

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite

I have .csv files which are saved with a "~MySpecialDelimiter~" as the "comma" character.  I've been importing them into my Sqlite3 database in other instances by replacing these values with commas.  However one of these files is a text files, and commas are used throughout.  This makes the file import go all wonky for obvious reasons.

How do I import from a "delimiter separated value" with an arbitrary delimiter in Sqlite?

I've found .separator and set that, but it's returning "expected 12 columns of data but found 1".

Answer (score 3):

The sqlite documentation seems to imply it only handles delimiter characters, not sequences. So you'll need to find a character that is never used in any of your files, and replace the ~MySpecialDelimiter~ with that.

You can then set the delimiter using either `.separator` (if using `.import`) or the 3rd parameter of `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ... USING CSVFILE ()`.

Comment: got a link?  I found the .separator character stuff earlier, but it's been giving me issues.  I'd like to read up on it.

Comment: Yea ok, that's what I had seen.  I see what you mean by 'implies' but it's not very clear on that.